# rails で複数ログインをサポートする認証系の gem (ライブラリ) はありますか?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

たとえば、 gmail や twitter は複数アカウントでのログインを実現しています。これらのように、複数アカウントでのログインを実現する方法には、どのようなものがありますか? それが実現できるライブラリなどはありますか?

---

2020/05/25 追記

複数アカウントでのログインとは、例えば gmail においては、個人のプライベート用のアドレスと、個人の仕事用の gmail アドレスそれぞれでログインができるようになっています。複数のアカウントでログインした際の挙動としては、 i. 単一アカウントでのログインと比べて、複数アカウントでログインした際には、アクティブなアカウントというのがそれら複数アカウントの中から選択できるようになり、アクティブなアカウントにおいては、単一アカウントでログインした場合とほぼ同じような操作性になる ii. アクティブなアカウントは複数アカウントの中から切り替えられる
を実現できている機能のことを、複数ログイン機能、と呼んでいます。

Comment: 「複数アカウントでのログイン」とはどういうことを目指したいのでしょうか、それっぽい言葉で説明を省くと明後日の回答がくるのではないかと危惧します。
1システムで複数のアカウントを持つことができることでしょうか、１アカウントで複数のシステムにログインできる仕組みでしょうか？一人の意図が複数のアカウントを持つことができるシステムのことでしょうか？

Comment: @あとわいと 追記しました。

Comment: (追記を見ても) "複数" が何に掛かっているのかが分かりづらい印象です。「ログアウトせずに複数アカウントで同時にログイン状態を維持して切り替えできる」、とかでしょうか？ / 例えばここ StackOverflow においてのメールアドレスやGoogleアカウントで「複数の方法で」ログインできる、とは違いますか？

Comment: この機能を使ったことがあれば何を聞きたいのかは自明だと思います。この機能を使ったことがない人には何を言ってるかわからないかもしれませんが、そういう人はどのみち回答はできないでしょうから、そういう人にも伝わる説明を求めても意味ないのではないでしょうか